# Less littering with less trashcans

Tags: social-psychology, perception

I live in Stockholm and recently visited Helsinki. I've lived a few different places in Sweden and only been to Helsinki in Finland. A big difference i noticed right away was the way cleaner streets, pathways and nature in general in Finland. I assumed this was due to similar reasons as a city like Växjö is rather clean where every morning a small army of workers show up and clean up the streets throughout the city, but this does not seem to be the case as the few pieces of trash that did end up in the streets stayed there for days on end (only so notable because the streets in general were so clean, in what other place would i have noticed *that* old pack of cigarettes so clearly??).

Being a smoker myself though I always throw my butts away appropriately and noticed something I would definitely not have expected: Far less trashcans. By a mile than stockholm. Here on the main streets I can be walking down a road and have trashcans within ~50 meters from one another, sometimes even more often, but there's almost always a trashcan in sight. In Helsinki I'd find myself regularly hanging on to my cigarette butt for several blocks until I found a place to dispose of it.

This doesn't make sense to me. I vaguely remember reading years and years ago about some analysis that showed more trashcans subconsciously makes people think of trash, and may lead to them adopting the "it's dirty anyway" mentality that lets people litter without much second thought, completely contradictory to the usual first step to combatting littering which would be more trashcans (trying to look up information on this has most sources stating some form of *more trashcans!!* right away which of course seems to make sense). At the time I dismissed it as one of the silliest things I'd read because obviously if there's always a trashcan in sight, people **must** be more inclined to throw their trash into the cans instead of the streets right? But Helsinki stands out to me as being cleaner than most places I've been with a very notable lack of ways to dispose of your trash.

I suspect that when it comes to the cleaner nature, this is a direct causation. People are already used to carrying their trash "home" with them or at least to a place to dispose of it, so they're more inclined to do it once they're far away from a trashcan (even far into a national park we found a grilling spot that I would shudder to think how dirty it would've been in most other countries I've been to, with people leaving cans and trash everywhere: The place didn't have a trashcan meaning people had to take their trash halfway back through the park, and they did. Not a piece of trash in sight). But what could the explanation for the cleaner streets in the city be? Is the effect I may or may not have read about years ago (because I really can't find much info on it now) a thing, or is this a cultural phenomenon? But if it was cultural and the culture payed great attention to throw their trash away, and it's generally agreed upon that more trashcans = less people littering, I'd assume that they'd be the first to put up a ton of trashcans as well. Are they just **so** good at disposing of their trash properly that they never even needed to put up more trashcans? This feels really unlikely...

And if this is actually a thing where the psychology of people gets impacted in reverse that clearly, can you think of any other similar concepts? I'd find it fascinating to hear about more real life examples of this (or **any** real life example if I'm completely making all of this up somehow and there's actually just a super easy explanation I've missed)

*Apologies in advance if the way this "question" is posed doesn't really fit here, but it was too intriguing to not at least try to find some interesting psychological factor if there is one :)*

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question is soliciting opinion-based discussion, which makes it off-topic here (this is a Q&A forum).  However, check out instead: [How long does an area clean-up help it stay clean?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/27336/7001)